# Communication between microservices using MassTransit and Rabbitmq

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

In .Net I had a solution with 2 microservice (API) and one shared layer (Shared Models). I wanted to send some data from one microservice to another using MassTransit and RabbitMQ. After implementing the code the logic worked, the message was published successfully and the consumer revoked.

Now I am trying to change a architecture of my project. In this case I have 3 different solutions each solution has an API project also I took my shared models in different solution and each microservice can reach it using assemblies. Now the main problem I have in this situation the message is published successfully but the consumer is not revoked. The versions of NuGet Packages are same.

This is my Dependency Injection for Consumer Microservice:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMessageBroker(this IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration)
{
MessageBrokerSettings messageBrokerSettings = new();

            configuration.Bind(MessageBrokerSettings.SectionName, messageBrokerSettings);
    
            services.AddSingleton(Options.Create(messageBrokerSettings));
    
            services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
            {
                busConfigurator.AddConsumer<GetCompanyIdsConsumer>();
    
                busConfigurator.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cur =>
                {
                    cur.Host(new Uri(messageBrokerSettings.Host), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(messageBrokerSettings.UserName);
                        h.Password(messageBrokerSettings.Password);
                    });
    
                    cur.ReceiveEndpoint("companyQueue2", oq =>
                    {
                        oq.PrefetchCount = 20;
                        oq.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
                        oq.ConfigureConsumer<GetCompanyIdsConsumer>(provider);
                    });
                }));
            });
    
            services.AddTransient<IEventBus, EventBus>();
    
            return services;
        }
```

And this is Dependency Injection for publisher microservice:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMessageBroker(this IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration)
{
MessageBrokerSettings messageBrokerSettings = new();

            configuration.Bind(MessageBrokerSettings.SectionName, messageBrokerSettings);
    
            services.AddSingleton(Options.Create(messageBrokerSettings));
    
            services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
            {
    
                busConfigurator.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cur =>
                {
                    cur.Host(new Uri(messageBrokerSettings.Host), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(messageBrokerSettings.UserName);
                        h.Password(messageBrokerSettings.Password);
                    });
                }));
    
                services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
    
            });
    
            services.AddTransient<IEventBus, EventBus>();
    
            return services;
        }
```

Consumer Class:

```
    public class GetCompanyIdsConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { var obj = context.Message; });
        }
    }
```

Publisher method:
`await _eventBus.PublishAsync(message, uri, cancellationToken);`

Do you have any suggestions? Is it a right approach to have each API in different solutions?

I wanted to send messages between microservices using MassTransit and Rabbit MQ for shared solution it worked but for different solutions it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [explained very clearly in the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages) the messages must have the same namespace and type name.