# How to define contract between services in rabbitmq?

Tags: .net, architecture, rabbitmq, masstransit

How to define and type in advance a contract between two services that are located in different solutions? For example, there is a publisher and a subscriber that are on different clusters. The publisher publishes a predefined event via mass transit, such as AdminGenerateCodeEvent:

```
await publishEndpoint.Publish(new AdminGenerateCodeEvent()
    {
        Id = 1,
        PresenterLink = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        ReceiverLink = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    });
```

which is defined in the publisher project, the subscriber subscribes to receive this event from rabbitmq

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<AdminGenerateCodeEvent> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{context.Message.Id}: {context.Message.ReceiverLink}");
    }
```

and must depend on AdminGenerateCodeEvent, but the subscriber's project is in a different repository and is a separate solution project. In the documentation for Rabbit mq it is possible to exchange byte streams, but how to predefine the contract for subscriber deserialization? Take out all the messages that are exchanged between services, and include them as a Nuget package in two projects? Or is there some concise solution to this problem?

AdminGenerateCodeEvent:

```
public class AdminGenerateCodeEvent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string PresenterLink { get; set; }

    public string ReceiverLink { get; set; }
}
```

This event is now in a separate rabbit mq contract project, and both subscriber and publisher projects depend on the message and contract project for rabbit mq.

Thanks in advance for helping me resolve this issue.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76245006/1882